# clock() behavior in ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

This is the reduced code to demonstrate the behavior.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DELAY  2.0

int main ( void) {
    static clock_t start;
    static double delay = 0.0;
    double elapsed = 0.0;
    clock_t stop;

    initscr ( );
    timeout ( 20); // milliseconds getch waits for a character

    if ( delay < .0001) {
        start = clock();
        delay = DELAY;
    }
    do {
        // getch ( );
        stop = clock();
        elapsed = (double)( stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        move ( 22, 0);
        printw ( "cps %ld elapsed %f\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC, elapsed);
        refresh ( );
    } while ( elapsed < delay);
    endwin ( );
    return 0;
}
```

Compiled and linked with `ncurses` it runs for about two seconds.
Uncomment `// getch ( );` recompile and link and it runs for about two hundred seconds.
The problem has been solved by using `clock_gettime()`.
I am curious why `clock()` is behaving strangely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On POSIX systems (like Linux or macOS) the [`clock`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock.html) function reports the **CPU** time used for the process. If it doesn't use any CPU time, like when it's waiting a lot of time, then you will get very small differences.

If you use [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_getres.html) with either `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` or `CLOCK_REALTIME` those are based on the *wall* clock of the system.

---

Note that the behavior of `clock` is different on [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/clock?view=msvc-170) where it's a representation of the wall clock.